# Strange behavior of GdipDrawLine

Tags: delphi, gdi+, gdi

I found a strange behavior of GDI+ (i try a GdipDrawLine). I have a simple form with paint box over it  [image: how they see in designer] and a simple code in OnPaint Event

```
procedure TForm1.pbPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pen: GPPEN;
  GDIDC: GPGRAPHICS;
  Brush: HBrush;
  R: TRect;
begin
  Brush := CreateSolidBrush(TColorRec.ColorToRGB(TColorRec.Green));
  R := Rect(0, 0, pb.Width, pb.Height);
  FrameRect(pb.Canvas.Handle, R, Brush);

  GdipCreateFromHDC(pb.Canvas.Handle, GDIDC);
  GdipCreatePen1(ColorRefToARGB(TColorRec.ColorToRGB(TColorRec.Red)), 3, UnitPixel, Pen);
  GdipSetPenDashStyle(Pen, DashStyleSolid);
  GdipDrawLine(GDIDC, Pen, 10, 10, 200, 200);

  TextOut(pb.Canvas.Handle, 10, 10, 'Text', 4);
  FrameRect(pb.Canvas.Handle, R, Brush);
  GdipDeletePen(Pen);
  GdipDeleteGraphics(GDIDC);
end;
```

This code produced a following picture [image: what we have when run a program] It looks strange, we have two FrameRect with equal parameters that produced a different output, so some function offset a graphic output, lets try to comment a GdipDrawLine and we get a [image: what we have when comment a GdipDrawLine] Ups it looks normal. So the GdipDrawLine offset a GDI output, i try they offset a GDI output only not GDI+.

So i have a questions. First is it normal and documented? I check a GdipDrawLine Microsoft help i found noting about offset. Second how to disable this offset.

Comment: I don't use Delphi, but if I convert your code into C++ I cannot reproduce your problem and it works normally : [Test-GdipDrawLine](https://i.ibb.co/mT3h9CT/Test-Gdip-Draw-Line.jpg)

Comment: I can confirm the outcome with Delphi XE7, but I cannot explain it otherwise than mixing GDI and GDI+ device contexts seems to be the cause. If you move the lines `  GdipDeletePen(Pen);  GdipDeleteGraphics(GDIDC);` up to the other `Gdip...` calls, that is before the `TextOut()` call, then the result is as you want it.

Comment: In fact, interoperability caveats between GDI and GDI+ are [documented here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311221/info-interoperability-between-gdi-and-gdi)